# Typescript - Encrypt object and keep all type/metadata information

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, serialization

I'm trying to find a way to store an object and retrieve it keeping all type information and metadata (descriptors, attributes, etc). All references I found used `JSON.stringify` (or some variation) before applying encryption but that only keeps the structure and primitive types values.

The objects to be encrypted shouldn't need decorators or specific parsers because I want to be able to do that with any object.

Is there any way to do that? Any nudge to helpful path would be very appreciated.

**EDIT #1:**

I'm not tied to encryption or serialization, whichever works. I'm trying to get `Util.inspect` to render the absolute same string before and after serialization/encryption.

`Util.inspect` options parameter:

```
{
  showHidden: true,
  depth: Infinity,
  colors: true,
  breakLength: Infinity,
  compact: true
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

For simple objects `JSON.stringify` > `JSON.parse` would work just fine. But some of the more complex ones - such as `http`'s `IncomingMessage` - lose a lot of information (i.e. hidden properties).

Comment: Can you please be clear here exactly what your goal and expected output is as there's a *big* difference between **serialisation** and **encryption**.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good call, I've edited the question to clarify those concerns.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I still do not follow. `JSON.stringify` -> `encrypt` -> `decrypt` -> `JSON.parse` should print the same object. 

Do you mean you want the order of the object keys preserved as well? So `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}` to not be reprinted as `{"key2":"value2", "key1":"value1"}`?

Comment: @Kousha For simple anonyomus objects that would work just fine... but there are some complex objects - such as `http`'s `IncomingMessage` - that a lot of information is lost.

Comment: You cannot serialize/encrypt functions. Only plain objects. This is not a Javascript problem. The same would exist in any other language.

Comment: @Kousha Yeah I'm looking for workarounds or alternatives. `JSON.stringify` can't be the best we have.